# How do you get the currently focused window in Titanium Mobile?

Tags: titanium

I'm attaching a resume event to the app and I want to detect what window is currently focused

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
  // what window is focused? visible?
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try Ti.UI.currentWindow - but I've had mixed results with it in the past.

The most basic option is to create a global var in your app.js to store the window, so on resume, just check that. You'll probably want to make a wrapper for windows so on open() you set your global with the window.

Answer (score 1):

just set a flag with on the every window focus event like

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('currentWindow',Ti.UI.currentWindow.title);
```

so you only need to request this flag..

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I wish to access the actual current window object. It's possible that I may have many windows opened (maybe on top of each other). I want to attach to Ti.App's `resume` event in the root window and when that event is fired, I want to check what window is currently visible.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in every window focus event

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('currentWindow',Ti.UI.currentWindow.title);
```

And Ti.UI.currentWindow.title should be basically the name of the file in which that window is being created.

Now just you have to do this on the resume event

```
var newwin_name= Ti.App.Properties.getString('currentWindow');
var newwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({url:newwin_name+'.js'});
newwin.open();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

first you will set the global event. and handle it to receive the windowTitle

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
  alert(e.windowTitle)
});
```

and in the place you want to fire this event make this

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('resume',{
windowTitle : Ti.UI.currentWindow.title
});
```

so you can send custom data to the global event

Answer (score 0):

The property 'Ti.UI.currentWindow' is available only if you used Ti.UI.createWindow.url method to load the javascript on the context. This method however was REMOVED since version 3.6.0 and the introduction of alloy (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-url) -> **Then Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow returns null**

The only way I was able to keep a pointer on the current window was to assign it on creation to a Global Variable on the Alloy.Globals collection, tho is a tricky method if you use several Windows and too many ways to navigate through those windows, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

var currentWindow = Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow();

Answer (score -1):

The focused window is the last opened!